# Quickly swapping mouse buttons on Windows

Tags: windows, mouse

I use my mouse with my left hand, so I invert the left and right click buttons.

But, at work, it's pretty common to people come to my workstation and do some quick work (show me how to do something or anything like that).

Everytime that someone uses my machine, the person is confused (because most of people are right handed).

**Is there any software that enables me to quick swap the mouse buttons? Something sitting on systray for instance would be great.**

Since this is really a quick thing, it's kinda unproductive to navigate to the Windows configuration and swap the thing. Normally I just tell the person about it and they use it awkwardly.

I'm using Windows 7 @ work. But if there is anything like for Linux or OS X too let me know (I use both @ home).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) can do what you need. It works on Windows 7, hides in the system tray, and has a portable version that you could install on your work computer without administrator privileges.

You can use it to swap the left and right mouse buttons by using this setting:

[image: X-button mouse control screenshot 1]

Furthermore, you can easily configure it to activate/deactivate using the Scroll Lock key:

[image: X-button mouse control screenshot 2]

Now all you have to do is tap <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> when a colleague walks in, then tap it again when they walk out.